# How do I include image resource files with an exe in visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I feel super silly because this has to have a really simple answer. I've been searching for hours now, but I just don't know what to do. (Sorry I'm also kind of new to this). Anyways,

How can i include an image resource with the built release version? I have the image in the project solution. But when I build the project the image doesn't transfer with it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Under Resource view, import the image ( the converted binary image is now part of your app).

Comment: It depends on the format of the image file... if the image file format is not handled in the resource file of the visual studio  then it should be given a thought